# How do I turn off "column box select" in visual studio code?

Tags: visual-studio

I seem to be unable to turn off box/column select. In other words, if I try to select across multiple lines, I only get a box select, as opposed to the usual behavior where entire lines are selected as I add lines.

I am using version 1.48.2 on a mac.

I must have pressed option+shift or some other such code inadvertently and now I can only select boxes. I have looked at my keyboard shortcuts but I don't know what to look for...

Unfortunately searching for solutions via google or SE only produces results for how to turn it on, not off! I don't know what the opposite mode is. "line select" seems to be just to select the current line, not for entire lines across multiline selections.

[example of current behavior.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZ2hT.jpg) I want the entire line "spaceship..." to be selected.

Answer (score 6):

Just found the answer myself looking for something else. There is a "Text Editor" setting  called "Editor: Column Selection" that controls this. The default is off, but I must have turned it on somehow without realizing it. Thanks to anyone who may have taken time to read this....

Comment: How do you find these settings?

Answer (score 0):

Cmd+8 is the shortcut to toggle the setting